# Symfony 2 stubs?

Tags: symfony, stub

I'm seeing some of SF2 components have a folder named stubs placed inside the Resources/ folder. I wonder what is it for? And for my bundle I need to define some global functions, would the stubs folder be a good location to place the files containing these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are a few meanings for stub. The most relevant I could find was one that described a stub as 'code that is used to stand in for some other programming functionality'.

I.e. acting as a substitute for code that is yet to be developed, or to simulate the behaviour of existing code that isn't usable (or viably usable) under certain circumstances, for example, in a development environment.

Comment: interesting. So that would mean it's not the very good place for placing functions?

Comment: I'd guess not. Maybe have an entities, handlers or services folder or something similar. I always find placing things like that quite difficult!